# Automate creation of some Solr cores on a Linux machine

Tags: solr

I need to create a bunch of solr cores on a Linux box. I can do this relatively easily with a combination of command line interactions to create the necessary directory structure, and the solr admin console to actually create the cores.

I would like to automate this process, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I can create the cores using the REST API, but the directory structure needs to already exist as far as I can tell. Also, I am a Windows user. Is there any way this can be done entirely from a Windows machine?

I'm not looking for code samples, I'm looking for advice on the technology/techniques I would use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The url for  creating core is `"http://localhost:8983/Solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=core-name&instanceDir=path/to/dir&config=solrconfig.xml&dataDir=data"`

Here you can write a scheduler for it creating the core. Before creating the core you can check if the instanceDir exist. If not you can create the same and map it to the core creating url.

Next is solr core requires the configset, you can create your own configset and add the required files to it. Again map the the config set path to the solr core url.

Data dir is the path where indexes are stored. Create the folder and map the path of it to the solr core creation url.

You can do the same by adding all these values in the database like storing the values of configset, instanceDir etc in the tables. Use those values for creating the core. You can change these values in the database as required. You need not have to change the values at the code side. Without the code modification it will continue working.

if you are running it on unix, then you can run the cron job for creating the core as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, the creating instanceDir is the part where I am really stuck. How do I automate that piece?